# How to setup server side of OpenSSH on Windows 10 for autologin?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I am trying to follow this tutorial on auto-login into SSH:
http://rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html
The objective is to make a script so my linux computer can shutdown my windows computer with a single script file, automatically.
The issue I'm having is that all the tutorials on internet are oriented of course to a linux-linux environment and the commands asked for configuring the server-side of the configuration, don't work for windows 10.

The idea is to use it in the LAN so I don't really mind "security" concerns.

So
How can I achieve auto-login on windows 10 ssh from a linux terminal?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed OpenSSH Server on the Windows installation and configured it to use the authentication method you wish to use?

Comment: Hello @Ramhound , yes I have, I can login into the account and everything.